# Loop drawing rectangles

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to make a basic tetris game, first I am looking to draw a grid to make sure that I am creating blocks as I want to, however I can't get my program to access my paintComponent method.

```
package tetris;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TetrisMain extends JFrame {

 final int BoardWidth = 10;
 final int BoardHeight = 20;
 public static int HEIGHT = 400;
 public static int WIDTH = 200;

 Timer timer;
 boolean isFallingFinished = false;
 boolean isStarted = false;
 boolean isPaused = false;
 int score = 0;
 int curX = 0;
 int curY = 0;
 int[][] grid = new int[BoardWidth][BoardHeight];

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Charles Walker - 1504185");
     frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     frame.setResizable(false);
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.repaint();
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponents(g);
     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     for (int i = 0; i < BoardWidth; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < BoardHeight; j++) {
             curX = grid[i][curY];
             curY = grid[curX][j];
             g.fillRect(WIDTH / BoardWidth, HEIGHT / BoardHeight, curX, curY);
         }
     }
 } 
}
```

Comment: use jpanel to draw graphics.and why do you create another frame ?`TetrisMain` is a jframe

Comment: Sorry, I'd just taken that out before I posted but still had the old code copied in, ignore that. As for using a JPanel to draw, how does that work differently? And how to I access my paintComponent to do so?

Comment: jframe is a heavy component.actually it's not a jcomponent so there is no paint component method.it's better to use a jpanel for drawing.if you extent clas from jpanel then you can override paintComponent method.add `@override` annotation yo will see the problem

Comment: can you tell what is borderWidth?how mush grids for x direction and y?what is the height,width of a grid cell?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic code to do what you want :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Name extends JFrame {
     public Name() {
         super("Name");
         setTitle("Application");
         setContentPane(new Pane());
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setSize(400,400);
         setResizable(true);
         setVisible(true);
         while (true){
              try { //Update screen every 33 miliseconds = 25 FPS
              Thread.sleep(33);
              } catch(InterruptedException bug) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              System.out.println(bug);
              }
              repaint();
         }
     }
     class Pane extends JPanel {
         public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //Here is were you can draw your stuff
             g.drawString("Hello World",0,20); //Display text
         }
     }
     public static void main(String[] args){
         new Name();
     }
}
```

I think you forgot that line to set the content pane :

```
setContentPane(new Pane());
```

and, important, you need a **while loop** to redraw :

```
while (true){
    try { //Update screen every 33 miliseconds = 25 FPS
    Thread.sleep(33);
    } catch(InterruptedException bug) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    System.out.println(bug);
    }
    repaint();
}
```